# Regex to grab string between a comma and a period

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like this

```
Allen, Mr. William Henry
```

and I want to grab the 'Mr' part.

I've tried this

```
[,](.*?)[.]
```

But this grabs the ', Mr.'

How can I grab only the 'Mr' part?

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed answers!! All them work great and actually teach me how to use regex. I really need to practice it and learn it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may *capture* `Mr` with a regular TRE regex using `regmatches` and `regexec`:

```
> s <- "Allen, Mr. William Henry"
> m <- regmatches(s, regexec(",\\s*([^.]*)", s))
> m[[1]][2]
[1] "Mr"
```

**Pattern details**:

- `,` - comma
- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^.]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ characters other than `.`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP9l72/1).

Comment: Clever - I have never used `regexec` - might have to start

Comment: ^ Seconded. I submitted another answer, but that one is neat.

Comment: This fails if you use regexpr() instead of regexec(), and I can't understand why. What is the purpose/difference between the two functions?

Comment: `regexec()` keeps *captured* texts while `regexpr()` only keeps *matches*.

Answer (score 1):

If every string in your data is of the form

`"NAME, TITLE. FIRSTNAME(S)`

Then you can also use

```
x <- "Allen, Mr. William Henry"
gsub("(.*),\\s(.*)\\.(.*)", "\\2", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this

```
s <- "Allen, Mr. William Henry"
sub(".*,\\s{0,}(\\w+)\\..*", "\\1", s)
```

### Logic

```
.*,       any characters until comma
\\s{0,}   spaces 0 to as many
\\w+      words at least one
\\..*     period followed by any character(s)

the "\\1" keep the pattern within the parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(s, "\\w+(?=\\.)")
#[1] "Mr"
```